# Eclipse Plugin Developement find out which workingSet an ICompilationUnit belongs to

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have an ICompilationUnit and try to find out which workingSet it belongs to , or if it even has a workingSet. I have looked at the diffrent methods that ICompilationUnit has, howeber i did not find anything that helps. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

A compilation unit may be a member of 0, 1, or many working sets. You will have to search through the list of working sets seeing which contain it.

Get the working sets with:

```
IWorkingSetManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();

IWorkingSet [] sets = manager.getAllWorkingSets();
```

for each working set get the members with:

```
IAdaptable [] members = set.getElements();
```

Members can be many things, `instanceof ICompilationUnit` may work for some members or you may need to adapt:

```
ICompilationUnit unit = (ICompilationUnit)member.getAdapter(ICompilationUnit.class);
```

Note: the exact syntax of the `getAdapter` call varies depending on the Eclipse release as generics support was added in 4.5.